# Programe Not Executing in Correct Order in Android Studio

Tags: if-statement, android-asynctask, boolean, order-of-execution

I want to check whether the email id entered by user is unique or not so for that initially I have my variable `Boolean valid = false;`. On clicking a button i am taking the email id entered and checking it for valid email id expression using regular expression and then i am using an asyntask to check its uniqueness. Code in my onclicklistner is

`if (emailid.matches(regexp) && emailid.length() > 0) {
                    new Validate().execute();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), valid.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if (valid) {
                        data.putString("eid", eid);
                        data.putString("firstname", firstname);
                        data.putString("lastname", lastname);
                        data.putString("emailid", emailid);
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GamesFragment.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email Address Already Exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Check Your Email Address", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }`

Here what problem i am facing is, for first time when i am entering an email which is unique and clicks the button, the `Validate()` asynctask checks and sets the `valid` variable to true, but it doesn't goes to next activity `GamesFragment` because i have declared `valid = false` initially. Now when i again click the button, then it goes to next activity as the `valid` variable is set to true because of previous click.
Now My `Validate()` asynctask is

```
private class Validate extends AsyncTask&lt;Void, Void, Void&gt; {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> emailId = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            emailId.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emailid));

            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("url/validate.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(emailId));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                iss = entity.getContent();

            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("pass 1", "Connection Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                        (new InputStreamReader(iss,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                iss.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
                code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

                if(code == 1)
                    valid = true;
                else
                    valid = false;
                Log.e("pass 3", "valid "+valid);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }
    }
```

Please help i am not getting why this is happening.

Comment: validate is in your same class right? @AdnanMomin

Comment: validate is my **inner class**

Comment: then pass postexecute method in your asynctask and in that check if code is 1 than navigate. see my updated answer

Comment: post execute is overriden method of async task.

Comment: @KDeogharkar thanks allot friend, your idea of moving my complete code in onPostExecute() solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create function to check validation.

```
private boolean function validate(String emailid){

if (emailid.matches(regexp) && emailid.length() > 0) {
return true;
}


return false;

}
```

use that function to decide event

```
if(validate(emailid)){ // if function return true then email is valid and good to go.

 new Validate().execute();


}
```

For second condition you have to check it in your async task `onPostExecute()` that is Validate();

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {

        super.onPostExecute(o);
        if(code == 1){

    // check if response is valid than 
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GamesFragment.class);
                        startActivity(i);
```

}
         }

Comment: i am able to check email id using regexp but the problem is in chhecking the uniqueness of email id. I mean the second if statement in my code. Also in my asynctask i am making http requests.

Comment: that you have to check in your post execute method my friend. I will update my answer.

Comment: yess so if the email is unique the i have to go to next activity. In my asynctask i am setting the `valid` variable to true if email is unique or false if email is already present.

Comment: let me update my post so you will get what i am doing.